# postgis error: when adding features geometry has z dimension but column does not

Tags: qgis, postgis, geometry, dxf

I have to define a geometry column in PostGIS for 2D points, but when I try to import points from DXF to postgres I get the following message:

> "postgis error: when adding features geometry has z dimension but
>   column does not"

Is there any way to change DXF files to be 2D geometry? I have tried this with the comand `Flatten` in autocad but the same error appears.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a more elegant solution, but can you import the points as 3-D points, and then create a 2-D point in Postgres? For example `ST_X( 3dpoint )` and `ST_Y( 3dpoint )` would give you the x and y coordinates so you could then create a point using:

```
ST_SetSRID(
    ST_MakePoint(
        ST_X( 3dpoint ), ST_Y( 3dpoint )
                 ), 900913)
```

I don't know what form your initial data is in, so perhaps you can just use the x and y values by themselves.

Comment: Hint: [ST_Force_2D](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Force_2D.html) is more elegant

Comment: Thanks - I was unaware of it. Happy to add it to my answer unless you'd prefer to answer yourself......

Answer (score 0):

DXF export only the rows and then copy and paste the features as a new vector layer

Comment: Your answer has been flagged because of its length. Can you elaborate more on how this answers the question?